# Error parsing json in android

Tags: android, json

This is a json response that i'm unable to parse. Please help me to parse this response.

> {
>        "status": "true",
>        "data": {
>           "userinfo": [
>               {
>                   "id": "77",
>                   "firstname": "Test",
>                   "lastname": ""
>               }
>           ]
>       }
>       }

And this is my android code.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

 ServiceHandler2 sh = new ServiceHandler2();

 String url="http://192.168.0.65/hostandguest/android/viewprofile?uid=77";

 String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler2.GET);

 Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

  if (jsonStr != null) {

    try {

         JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
         String status = jsonObj.getString("status");

          if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

            JSONArray   Userarr=jsonObj.getJSONArray("userinfo");
            String  data=jsonObj.getString("data");
             for(int i=0;i<Userarr.length();i++)
              {
                JSONObject c = Userarr.getJSONObject(i);
                String Fname=c.getString("firstname");
                Fname_arr.add(Fname);
                Log.v("Fname",Fname);                   
              }
            }
            else {
                  Log.v("Status", "false");
                 }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: It's always usefull to post the error it returns.

Comment: Did you getting any response?? if yes then you can check my answer. it will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get data josnObject first as:-

```
JSONArray   Userarr=jsonObj.getJsonObject("data").getJSONArray("userinfo");
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSONArray   Userarr=jsonObj.getJSONArray("userinfo");` would require `jsonObj` to contain the array "userinfo". This is not the situation you have presented. That array is inside a json sub object named "data".

```
        JSONObject jsonSubObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray  Userarr=jsonSubObj.getJSONArray("userinfo");
```

should be a fix. I've not checked for other errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting first `userinfo` object and then after `data` it's wrong.

I had changed like the following way you have to do this thing.

**userinfo** is sub array of **data** object.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ServiceHandler2 sh = new ServiceHandler2();

        String url = "http://192.168.0.65/hostandguest/android/viewprofile?uid=77";

        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler2.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {

            try {

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String status = jsonObj.getString("status");

                if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

                    JSONObject dataObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONArray infoObj = dataObj.getJSONArray("userinfo");

                    for (int i = 0; i < infoObj.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = Userarr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String Fname = c.getString("firstname");
                        Fname_arr.add(Fname);
                        Log.v("Fname", Fname);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.v("Status", "false");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```